# For loop while parsing xml in php?

Tags: php, xml, loops, for-loop

I am trying to create a for loop that will parse out different elements of xml doc using php.  It parses when I put the number of the entry in the line:

```
$s = $xml->entry[0]->children($namespaces['s']);
```

However I tried to replace the number with "i" to count through each of the entries in the xml doc and I get an error (Fatal error: Call to a member function children() on a non-object in /home/content/c/a/s/cashme/html/buylooper/xml.php on line 10).  How do I resolve this?

```
<?php
$url = 'xml-file.xml'; 
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url); 
$namespaces = $xml->entry->getNameSpaces(true); 

for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i += 1){

$s = $xml->entry[i]->children($namespaces['s']); 
$title = $s->product->title; 

//print 
echo $retailer;

}
?>
```

Comment: that means that `$xml->entry[i]` doesn't exist for some value of `i`.

Comment: @Ben: Post that as an answer so sharataka can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use $i, instead of i.

*As a side note:*

This bug should become **very** obvious on a development machine with:

- [display_errors](http://au.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) turned on, and
- [error_reporting](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) set to E_ALL (or even E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE)

you would get a warning like `Use of undefined constant i - assumed 'i'`

*(unless you have defined i as a constant somewhere but that's an odd constant name)*